# Missing my first row in retrieving data base

Tags: php, sql

I am trying to retrieve data and simply put it into my database . The $bid , $bid1 , $bid2 , bidpricepl , offerpricepl are already defined. Other then all the row decription being retreived from db , there is one row , profit and loss which is a variable . Foreach row , the value of this variable is being pushed down one notch , means in placement 2, the value is for place ment 1. I have attached an image so that you guys would understand. whats the issue with my query ? EG TABLE

OrderNumber:   Profit Loss:
sadasdasd     BLANK 
sadasdasd        1
sadasdasd    2 
sadasdasd        3

Query for calling and displaying

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM opentrades"; //You don't need a ; like you do in SQL
$result = mysql_query($query);
echo "<table border = '1px'>"; // start a table tag in the HTML
echo "<tr><td>" . "Order Number" . "</td><td>" . "Selection" . "</td><td>" . "Date" . "</td><td>" . "Type" . "</td><td>" . "Size" . "</td><td>" . "Bid Price" . "</td><td>" . "Offer Price" . "</td><td>" ."Stop Loss" . "</td><td>" . "Take Profit" . "</td><td>" ."Profit/Loss"."</td><td>" ."Close"."</td></tr>" ;  //$row['index'] the index here is a field name

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_BOTH)){   //Creates a loop to loop through results
echo "<tr><td>" . $row['trade_id'] . "</td><td>" . $row['selection'] . "</td><td>" . $row['date'] ."</td><td>" . $row['type'] ."</td><td>" . $row['size'] ."</td><td>" . $row['bidprice'] ."</td><td>" . $row['offerprice'] ."</td><td>" . $row['stoploss'] ."</td><td>" . $row['takeprofit'] ."</td><td>" . $bidpricepl  . "</td><td><a href ='delete.php?id=".$row['trade_id']."'>X</a></td></tr>";  
if ($row['selection']=='eur/usd')
            {
            $bidpricepl=$bid;

            $offerpricepl=$bid1;

            }
    elseif ($row['selection']=='usd/jpy')
            {
            $bidpricepl=$bid2;

            $offerpricepl=$bid3;

            }
    elseif ($row['selection']=='usd/cad')
            {
            $bidpricepl=$bid4;

            $offerpricepl=$bid5;

            }
    elseif ($row['selection']=='eur/jpy')
            {
            $bidpricepl=$bid6;

            $offerpricepl=$bid7;

            }
    elseif ($row['selection']=='eur/chf')
            {
            $bidpricepl=$bid8;

            $offerpricepl=$bid9;

            }
    elseif ($row['selection']=='gbp/usd')
            {
            $bidpricepl=$bid10;

            $offerpricepl=$bid11;

            }
    elseif ($row['selection']=='aud/usd')
            {
            $bidpricepl=$bid12;

            $offerpricepl=$bid13;

            }
    elseif ($row['selection']=='usd/chf')
            {
            $bidpricepl=$bid14;

            $offerpricepl=$bid15;

            }



}
echo "</table><br>";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try moving the `if` code to be before the `echo` statement.

At the moment you are working out the value after you have output the line in the table.

E.g.

```
if ($row['selection']=='eur/usd')
..
elseif ($row['selection']=='usd/jpy')
elseif ($row['selection']=='usd/cad')
elseif ($row['selection']=='eur/jpy')
elseif ($row['selection']=='eur/chf')
elseif ($row['selection']=='gbp/usd')
elseif ($row['selection']=='aud/usd')
elseif ($row['selection']=='usd/chf')

echo "<tr><td>" . $row['trade_id'] . "</td><td>" . $row['selection'] . "</td><td>" . $row['date'] ."</td><td>" . $row['type'] ."</td><td>" . $row['size'] ."</td><td>" . $row['bidprice'] ."</td><td>" . $row['offerprice'] ."</td><td>" . $row['stoploss'] ."</td><td>" . $row['takeprofit'] ."</td><td>" . $bidpricepl  . "</td><td><a href ='delete.php?id=".$row['trade_id']."'>X</a></td></tr>";
```